# Issues with Creating DB connection to Apache Derby Database

Tags: java, database, jdbc, database-connection, derby

I am working on a Java project where I make connections to  an apache derby database. I have followed below -

1. I have downloaded Apache Derby Zip file and extracted archive to a folder.
2. I created environment variables DERBY_HOME, DERBY_INSTALL same way as they've asked for.
3. I started database server using startNetworkServer.bat in the bin directory of database folder.
4. I was able to connect to the database server using a Database Manager called JetBrains DataGrip. it worked fine and was able to create tables and inserted data.
5. But when I used the dbURL (which was used in Database Client) in my java program I'm getting ClassNotFound exception.
6. Here is the class path I have seen when running the database server.
   D:/DevelopmentWorkspace/RunTimes/ApacheDerby10_12/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar;D:/DevelopmentWorkspace/RunTimes/ApacheDerby10_12/db-
   derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbynet.jar;D:/DevelopmentWorkspace/RunTimes/ApacheDerby10_12/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbyclient.jar;D:/Develop
   mentWorkspace/RunTimes/ApacheDerby10_12/db-derby-10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbytools.jar;D:/DevelopmentWorkspace/RunTimes/ApacheDerby10_12/db-derby
   -10.12.1.1-bin/lib/derbyoptionaltools.jar
7. Below is the exception I'm seeing

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
Error occurred connecting database  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

8. I could clearly see that derby.jdbc.ClientDriver is already there in derbyclient.jar file which was already there in classpath mentioned eariler but still I am receiving error but in Database manager its fine.

Please help.

Comment: what IDE do you use? and have you added the derbyclient.jar to the build path?

Comment: Include the **full** exception in your question. And if it says, "see the next exception", do this: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Hello MaxG, Thank you so much for giving solution in your question. I didn't put derbyclient.jar file in build path which was why I got exceptions. When I was trying to find out why the exception is getting thrown I thought that derbyclient.jar file is in localclasspath when I started derbyclient will be accessible to Application Eclipse IDE also. but with your answer's help I figured it was not added in application build path.